# When I was using SQLCMD -L command in command prompt a dialog box will appears showing T-SQL execution command line utility has stopped working

Tags: sql, sql-server

This box is opened when I am trying to run the `SQLCMD -L` command in `cmd.exe`:

[image: Error message]

Comment: try adding the -S parameter to connect to the server too

Comment: Thanks but what will be the syntax for it

Comment: showing error.                                                                          sqlcmdSqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. .Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: the fact it is now not crashing but giving a connection error makes me think it didn't like no knowing what server to connect to

Comment: Please restart your Windows then try again - HTH ;).